# Jar that read file

Tags: java, docker, jar

I have a code that deals with elasticsearch index. One of its steps, the program needs to read a jsonschema file in order to continue its execution. The code works well on my machine, but when I execute it as jar file inside a docker container, it gives me the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: dm.jsonschema (No such file or directory)
```

the code that loads the schema is:

```
public class loadSchema {

private static final String JSON_SCHEMA_DOCUMENT = "dm.jsonschema";
....
public static JsonSchema tryLoadJSONSchema() {
    JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
    JsonNode cdmSchema = null;
    try {
        cdmSchema = JsonLoader.fromPath(JSON_SCHEMA_DOCUMENT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

I placed the jsonschema file next to the jar file in the container, but it keeps giving me the same error. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: please try this path:  new FileReader(new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + File.separator+JSON_SCHEMA_DOCUMENT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relative path of the `File` is resolved from wherever you are starting the `java` executable (mind the `user.home`), not from where the jar archive was located.

The best approach would be externalising this file location using a system property. For example if you define a `jsonSchemaPath` property:

```
String path = Sytem.getProperty("jsonSchemaPath");
JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
JsonNode cdmSchema = JsonLoader.fromPath(path);
```

Then you can change it in the java command:

```
java -jar yourcode.jar -DjsonSchemaPath=/path/to/dm.jsonschema
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution is working fine.
But is there a way to get the relative path inside the code itself rather than passing the path as an argument?